# Redirecting to a url with an id in it, based on what the user clicks

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I have read other solutions and none of them have helped. So the idea is, users send messages, those messages have replies, to view the relpies it redirects users to `/reply/<message_id>` when the user clicks a hyperlink. I have attached the relevant code below.

app.py:

```
@app.route('/reply/<message_id>')
def reply(message_id):
    return render_template('reply.html', message_id = message_id)
```

index.html:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
          var message_id = 0 ;
          socket.on( 'connect', function() {
            socket.emit( 'my event', {
              data: 'User Connected'
            } )
            var form = $( 'form' ).on( 'submit', function( e ) {
              message_id++
              e.preventDefault()
              let user_input = $( 'input.message' ).val()
              socket.emit( 'my event', {
                message_id : message_id,
                message : user_input
              } )
              $( 'input.message' ).val( '' ).focus()
            } )
          } )
          console.log("we are before the method,a nd mid is " + mid + " of type " + typeof mid)
          socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
            console.log( msg )
            if( typeof msg.message_id !== 'undefined' ) {
              $( 'h3' ).remove()
              console.log("msg.message_id is " + msg.message_id + typeof msg.message_id)
              var mid = msg.message_id
              console.log("we are before the method,a nd mid is " + mid + " of type " + typeof mid)
              $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div>'+mid+'  '+msg.message+'  <a href="{{ url_for('reply', message_id='X') }}"'.replace('X', mid)'>reply</a></div>' ))
            }
          })

        </script>
```

reply.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The reply </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, your message id was  {{ message_id }}!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is happening at the moment, is when I click `reply` it redirects me to `/reply/` and then says cannot be found. I expect it to redirect me to `/reply/2` or whatever message id I click on. Thanks for any help

Comment: Try adding `console.log("Mid value is: " + mid);` line before the line you specified in index.html, I suspect it's undefined

Comment: I did that, it gives the number, I even did `typeof`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `mid` is a javascript variable, you can't mix this with Jinja code. The Jinja rendering will interpret `mid` as a Python variable, which in your case has not been set at the time of rendering.

To solve, move the variable out of the Jinja code. To keep the `url_for` working, you'll need to still provide a value for `message_id`. For example:

```
...' <a href="{{ url_for('reply', message_id='X') }}"'.replace('X', mid) + '>...'
```

Comment: For this, I get "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 - Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's confusing, can you add `methods=['GET']` to the route definition, and add the full html in your question?

Comment: Added the methods=['GET'] to the route (index). It seems to not be working. I also included the main bit in the html file in the question above. Thanks